# Why the plugin cordova of qr code scan doesn't work?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have to develop an app that doas an qr code scan but my code doesn't work. I already installed ngcordova and the plugin and the plugin of camera just for sure. Following error keeps popping.

Error:

```
?ionicplatform=android:28 ReferenceError: cordova is not defined
    at Object.scan (ng-cordova.min.js:7)
    at controllers.js:10
    at ionic.bundle.js:56230
    at Object.ready (ionic.bundle.js:2140)
    at Object.ready (ionic.bundle.js:56223)
    at Scope.$scope.scan (controllers.js:9)
    at fn (eval at compile (ionic.bundle.js:27638), <anonymous>:4:203)
    at ionic.bundle.js:65427
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30395)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30495)
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
        <title></title>

        <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
        <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
        -->

        <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
        <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

        <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
        <!-- your app's js -->
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
      </head>

      <body ng-app="starter">
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
      </body>
    </html>
```

controller:

```
    angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngCordova'])
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

    })
    .controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPlatform,
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner) {
      $scope.scan = function(){
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function(barcodeData) {
            // Success! Barcode data is here
          }, function(error) {
       // An error occurred
        });
      });
     };
    })
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you run it on mobile device? It won't work in web browser

Comment: It's not working in the smartphone also

Comment: Did you build the app or try on mobile browser? It will work only if you build it. If it doesn't work as app, do what error does it throw?

Comment: I tried on device and not work

Comment: @FelipeCustódio  was there any success ??